# External templates in vue-router

Tags: vuejs2, django-templates, vue-component, vue-router

I am new to Vue and I have already migrated a small application to it, but now I wanted to add routing in the front end level, so I started looking at vue-router.

My components use `inline-template` because they are placed inside templates of a django application. This way, the django ecosystem takes care of the localization and also offers more information to logged-in users.

I could not find a way to make my components work with vue-router. I even tested using `x-templates` and it just does not work unless the template is a string inside the JS code.

Is it possible for vue-router to use external file templates? If not, how does vue-router handle the situation where templates are generated by a backend server?

Comment: before you get too deep, make sure you understand how the router works, especially the trade-offs of router modes. If you use history, you'll have to implement a router with django, otherwise you'll likely need to implement SPA. Either way, if you're implementing javascript routes within a backend framework, there's going to be some pain. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: actually the only thing I need is to store the templates for the components used in the routes in an external file.  I could not find anywhere an example of vue-router working with `inline-template` and using `x-templates` I am having an odd error where the root app tries to render the component templates and fails because it does not have the data. My components are global components because they are used in several places and I am using a global event bus and Vuex to share data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found how to make it work. The trick was to place the `x-templates` **outside the root Vue app element**. This way the root Vue app did not tried to render them and then they were rendered by their components.